# What is the right hand fingering on this score in blue color?

Tags: piano, fingering

Title of the score is whistle while you work. What should be the *academic* fingering on the right hand C-E chord shown in blue of this score for "Whistle while You Work"?

I thought that it was natural to put 1-3. But is true ?
If I do that, I don't respect the semi-breve note B.

Also, what is meaning *silence* actually ? If I use the sustain to keep the semi-breve note B, then by definition, I don't respect the silences of the left hand.

[image: "Whistle while You Work" score]

Comment: What is the key signature of this piece?

Comment: @guidot - it's going to be in key C.

Comment: My best guess to the silence issue is, that is intended as indication for the piano, that no singing takes place.

Comment: @guidot : this is C

Comment: Please add the title of the piece, because it directly impacts the answers.

Comment: Various people have talked about a "silence" indication, but I cannot see the word "silence" anywhere. What does it refer to? As pointed out elsewhere, "sifflé" means "whistled".

Comment: @Aaron it's ["Whistle While You Work"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whistle_While_You_Work) from _[Snow White and the Seven Dwarfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snow_White_and_the_Seven_Dwarfs_(1937_film))_.

Comment: @phoog I know what it is; the question should be edited to include that information, since it's central to the answer.

Comment: @Aaron you can't really think that the identity of the piece is central to the answer since you answered the question without reference to the identity of the piece.  But if you feel so strongly that the question should include the information then you can edit the question yourself.

Comment: @phoog I directly addressed it, but without naming it, because I was leaving that to the OP, when I explained why the "silence" marking was there. If I must, I will eventually edit the question.

Comment: @Aaron there is no "silence" marking.

Comment: @phoog Yes. I erroneously followed OPs lead there. I've fixed the post.

Comment: @BrianChandler the word "silence" is not present, but the French word for "rest" is "silence," so it's possible that the question is about the rests in the left hand.  Mathieu Krisztian: the English word for the signs on beats 2 and 4 of the left hand part is "rest."  Is that what you meant by "silence"?

Comment: @phoog yes this was my meaning of the word silence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Play the B semi-breve with thumb, and stretch a bit for E and G. The easiest option for the pairs of notes is then 3 and 5 for each pair, bouncing them, as they're staccato. That way, there's no pedal needed, and l.h. can 'play' the rests, as required.

Siffle surely means whistle, not silence - as the song's about whistling while you work... So, whistle the tune rather than sing it - there's no words anyhow!

Comment: your answer is interesting, but most teachers say that one should play with 1 and 3 (their answer does not work since if we do that we don't respect the B semi-breve)

Comment: You've asked 'most teachers'? I don't even  know 'most teachers'. And if that's their answer, they're wrong!!! It's only natural if there's no note held *under* the C, but here there is.

Comment: yes. I'm really convinced that your answer is the good way to do it, but as a matter of a fact, I have encountered real piano teachers who swear that one should use the sustain and should play the blue notes with 1 3. (real meaning that I see in person)

Comment: Just proves there are real piano teachers and 'real' piano teachers...  Please ask them to justify the unjustifiable!

Comment: @MathieuKrisztian Have you studied this specific song with a teacher? Any teacher who knows it would not recommend pedal, though they very well might recommend pedal is similar situations in other pieces.

Comment: @Aaron : yes I studied with a professional piano teacher this specific song. And since I didn't trust him, I moved to this forum in order to ask. Now I know that he was wrong.

Comment: @MathieuKrisztian It's good you went for a second opinion. That teacher definitely gave poor advice.

Comment: @Aaron. I checked on the piano and the sound is much better by doing the variante that Tim gave, for example, as compared to the one with sustain and 13

Comment: @MathieuKrisztian That's definitely true, though as I describe in my own post, I don't like 53 there, because I have to contract my hand too much and unnecessarily.

Comment: @Aaron - this harks back to our fingering discussion. My little hands cope pretty well. And there's time (during the apres-staccato) to move 3 and 5 parallel.

Comment: @Tim Yes, the timing isn't as issue. I just don't like 135 so close together when there are other, easier (for me) options.

Comment: "sifflé" means _whistled._  The singer is supposed to whistle the melody at that point.

Comment: @phoog Ah, but I see I followed OPs lead in error regarding the "silence".

Comment: @Aaron having snooped a bit and found that OP asked a rather technical question on [French.SE], in French, about Rousseau's writing style, I'm quite sure that nobody is following OP's lead in thinking that _sifflé_ means "silence," because OP knows exactly what _sifflé_ means.  Rather, everyone has been led astray by misunderstanding what OP was asking about because he used the English word "silence" instead of "rest" to translate French _silence_.

Comment: 'Rest' is indeed 'silence' or 'pause' in the French musical language.

Answer (score 3):

There is not a standardized fingering for this situation.

Were it not for the sustained B, the typical fingering would be 53 - 24 - 13; however, that obviously doesn't work in this situation.

The sustain pedal is also not an option here. The "bouncy" nature of the song means that the rests and staccatos must be clearly heard, and pedaling would obscure them.

The "blue" chord has two main options:

1. 23
2. 24

As discussed, finger 1 isn't available, finger 5 unduly cramps the hand, and using 34 requires a space between 3 and 4 that tends to be uncomfortable, though some pianists don't mind it.

Beyond that, which one to use is purely personal.

---

My most likely fingering for the measure would be (thumb on B) 24 - 53 - 24 - 53.

- The initial 24 because that's what I would have used at the end of the previous measure for the same two notes, and since I have to move my thumb from G to B, repeating the 24 fingering gives me the easiest and most accurate result.
- The I go to 53, because it requires a fairly significant movement from the previous chord. This helps be get a good staccato and solid beat-one emphasis.
- 24 is next because it's the obvious next choice after 53.
- Then 53 again, because those fingers are already in position. And since it's staccato, it's an easy setup for the next measure, where I'll want to use 135 for the first chord.

Comment: There is not a standardised fingering for a good many situations! Recommended ones, maybe!

Comment: @Tim Not in this case. It's up to the pianist.

Comment: My point exactly!

Comment: @Tim I don't get it. Your point seems to be that there are generally recommended fingerings for this situation, which there aren't.

Comment: Recommended ones, MAYBE! (maybe NOT). Sorry, I don't subscribe to standardised or, for that matter 'recommended' fingerings. Some of my students have had to, and prefer even different fingerings from each other on the same piece

Comment: @Tim I'm totally lost. There are not generally recommended fingerings for this situation. I don't understand the point you're trying to make, unless you're agreeing with me that the choice here is individual.

Comment: You're digging too deeply! I agree with you *here*, but try to point out that it's very often the case there's no recommended fingering that would work for, say, 50%. Recommended is a poor choice. Suggested may be more apposite?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145721/discussion-between-aaron-and-tim).

Comment: It's exhausted, and so am I ..! I'll join in later after a lie down in a darkened room!

Comment: Since OP's given name is _French_ I rather suspect that "Also, what is meaning silence actually?" doesn't mean "what does _sifflé_ mean?" but rather "what do the rests in the left hand mean?"

Comment: @phoog - yes, OP is asking what a 'rest' actually represents. Pretty straightforward answer there!